# Getting an HTTP response to the global scope

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the response value from the `get()` method to use somewhere else in my code. Here is the code:

```
$.get('all-document-types', function( response ) {
    var data = [];
    $.each(response,function(index,value){
        data.push(value.document_type);
    });
    return data;
});
```

However, I am getting a undefined variable if I tried to access it outside of the callback function. So how can I get value?

Comment: Define `var data = []` outside of the callback function.

Comment: you could assign it to `window.whatever` BUT BUT BUT ! remember that the response happens asyncron and outside of this function `window.whatever` will not be assinged for some time. You probably want to check out `$.get(...).then().done().fail()` family of functions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)